# using image picker controller the app is randomly crashed in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode8

I am creating an iPad app which have more than 100 question. User get answare each of the questions and also take a picture for every questions. When i run thease app in ios 9 it's work fine but when the project run into iOS 10, the app is crashed(when user take more than 30 images). i couldn't find any solutions. 
here is my sample code....

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInf{


isImageChanged = YES;
[self.btnSelectImage setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    //Edited by Sarfaraj on 10th Sept, 2014 == >

    [popOverSelectImage2 dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

    [self.captionView removeFromSuperview];

    UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];

    //        vc.view = self.captionView;

    vc.view.frame = self.captionView.frame;

    [vc.view addSubview: self.captionView];



    /*

     [vc.view setFrame:self.captionView.frame];

     for (UIView *object in self.captionView.subviews) {



     [vc.view addSubview:object];

     }

     */

    // < ==

    [popOverSelectImage dismissPopoverAnimated:NO];

    popOverSelectImage = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];


    [popOverSelectImage setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(self.captionView.frame.size.width, self.captionView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];



    //popOverSelectImage.contentViewController = vc;


    [popOverSelectImage presentPopoverFromRect:currBtnRectForPopoverImage inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight animated:NO];
}
else
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

imageToSave = image;
```

}

Also i convert picking images. Can any one assist me?It's great helpfull for me. And one more thing, when i run the project into simulator, it doesn't crashed.And console part i am getting --> Communications error:  { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" =>  { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }

Comment: wat does crash say ?

Comment: i got only memory warning into console part, when i take more than 30  images. but iOS 9, i am not getting any crash. Why?

Comment: Have you added photo gallery access privacy in info.plist file.?

Comment: are you getting memory issue Warning ?

Comment: Yes Dhruv. I added photo gallery access privacy in info.plist file.

Comment: Yes. i got memory issue warning, when i run the project into ios 10. But when i run in ios 9 , that time i am not getting any memory issue. @iOS Geek

Comment: iOS10 have some memory issue yes even I too face in iOS10 you must use thumbnails instead of original pictures being shown . imagepicker show original image yes, you can make use of Photos FrameWork to get all pictures from Gallery and compress image occurring to make use of less memory need Demo code for Photos Framework to get images ?

Comment: Yes sir, Please provide the demo code for Photo Framework to get images.(Objective c)

Answer (score 0):

I think using dispatch may solve this problem, try using

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

          // your code

        });

    }
```

Comment: ami i use this code into imagepicker controller delegate method? @z

Comment: i also use 
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
        imageData = [self useImage:image];
        [self.btnSelectImage setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.imagePicker=nil;
    }];
but nothing happen into ios 10.

Comment: when i use a imagepicker delegate which you provide, i am getting error form this line........  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
 and error says "undeclare identifier info"

Comment: can you please check my updated question? I am getting that type of error. @ Zღk

Comment: looking at  your image, the only thing i am getting is that your device connection gets lost @Abir

Comment: when i saw first time, i am also thiking. but it's not right. When debag area 
says... 'Communications error: { count = 1, contents = "XPCErrorDescription" => { length = 22, contents = "Connection interrupted" }' . after that image popup is arise and app going to crash

Comment: ios 9, it works fine. When i run the project into iOS 10 device, it's going to crash randomly. i am implemented your code, but nothing happen.
please help me out with this situation, @Zღk